# Problems with C Shell bug: localpath: undefined variable

Tags: linux, shell, redhat, csh

I am not experienced in Linux nor in shell command.

The path that i stored the files are /home/cadence

I have tried with other few other solutions with .csh error and after many trials, this was my final result and it did not come into a fruition unfortunately. The error that I received is I received an error with "localpath: Undefined variable"

Below is the complete source code and i'm not sure how to go further with it.

```
#        % source cadence_setup.csh

# edit the path of environment

setenv CadenceHOME /home/cadence

# Set environment variables for Cadence software,

setenv CDSHOME          /home/cadence/IC618-500-8
setenv MMSIMHOME        /home/cadence/SPECTRE19-10-199
setenv PVSHOME          /home/cadence/PVS19-11-000
setenv ASSURAHOME       /home/cadence/ASSURA416-001-618
setenv XCELLHOME        /home/cadence/XCELLIUMMAIN19-03-008
setenv QUANTUSHOME      /home/cadence/QUANTUS20-10-00
setenv GENUSHOME        /home/cadence/GENUS19-12-000
setenv INNOVUSHOME      /home/cadence/INNOVUS19-12-000
setenv LCUHOME          /home/cadence/LCU4.30.002

# Set license file location for Cadence software
setenv  CDS_LIC_FILE    5280@sjflex3:5280@sjflex2:5280@sjflex1:5280@srv-sgtrn2

##################################################################
## DO NOT update any env. Variable below:
##################################################################
setenv  LM_LICENSE_FILE     $CDS_LIC_FILE

# Set Artist Netlisting Mode to Analog    #
setenv  CDS_Netlisting_Mode     Analog

# Set these variables in case we need to troubleshoot PVS failures

# Set variables to make Linux happy
setenv  LANG            en_US


# Set your program search path properly ....                   
# Build up a list of all of the options.  Please verify the localPath snd sysPath settings are valid 

# set   localPath = (. ~/bin ~/local/bin /usr/local/pvt /usr/ucb /usr/local \
#       /usr/local/bin /usr/local/Public/bin /opt/Acrobat4/bin \
#       /usr/lib/openoffice/program /sbin /usr/X11R6/bin )

set cdsPath1=$LCUHOME/tools/bin \
            $CDSHOME/tools/bin \
            $CDSHOME/tools/dfII/bin \
            $MMSIMHOME/tools/bin \
            $PVSHOME/tools/bin \
            $ASSURAHOME/tools/bin \
            $XCELLHOME/tools/bin \
            $QUANTUSHOME/tools/bin \
            $GENUSHOME/tools/bin \
            $INNOVUSHOME/tools/dfII/bin )


# set   sysPath = (/usr/ucb /usr/etc /usr/openwin/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /bin )

# Changing the order here since pvs executable in /usr/sbin conflicts with PVE
# installation

set path=( $cdsPath1 $localPath $sysPath )

set PATH=( $path)

set     filec
setenv  history 50
```

Comment: See my answer to your question. Aside from this, if you, are you say, inexperienced with Shell programming, why then do you start with such an exotic shell like _csh_, which is [not ideal for programming](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) anyway, instead of using a more common one, like _bash_ or _zsh_, where you can find more knowledge people, once you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing `set path=( $cdsPath1 $localPath $sysPath )`, but don't have anything assigned to `localPath`. Do a

```
setenv localPath ( /whatever/path/you /would/like/to/see/here )
```

before using this variable.